# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RouteComponentProps<{},,>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

So I'm quite new to React, and especially new to Typescript. I'm trying my best to wrap my head around it all so bare with me!

1. index.tsx
2. Router.tsx (all of the different routes)
3. LandingFrame.tsx (page layout)

```js
import React from 'react';

import LandingMain from './LandingMain'

const LandingFrame = () => {
    return (
        <LandingMain/>
    );
}

export default LandingFrame;
```

4. LandingMain.tsx (main)

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const YES = gql`
  query yes {
    yes {
      id
      data
      data {
        data
        data
      }
    }
  }
`;

const LandingMain = ({ history }: RouteComponentProps<{}>) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(YES);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>landing-page.js</h1>
      {data.yes 
        ? <p>Welcome back, {data.yes.data}</p> 
        : <p>Welcome back, Anon</p>
      }
    </div>

  );
};

export default LandingMain;
```

(on a 2nd note) I'm hoping that by splitting the landing page, the frame would load first, following the graphql query in the main component. That way when the page loads it doesn't only return `<p>Loading...</p>` on a blank page before loading the rest.

```
TypeScript error in LandingFrame.tsx(22,14):
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>': history, location, match  TS2739
```

At this point I'm just trying to split up as much code as I can. But while doing so I noticed that TS won't let me import a component as easily as React would. From what I've read, I need to pass props somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return (
    <LandingMain/>
);
```

LandingMain expects to recieve routeComponentProps, but you are rendering it without said props. You need to add the props expected by the component.

It's my understanding that landing frame is also receiving RouteComponentProps, so this should work

```
const LandingFrame = (props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) => {
    return (
        <LandingMain {...props} />
    );
}
```

Comment: You should also avoid using RouteComponentProps in a component that isn't being rendered with a path prop (in the same file a router, basically). That's why most router libs add hook or a context that allows you to access the state for anywhere, take a look at the documentation for you lib.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for an example of what you meant in the comment regarding hooks with react-router v5.1? This works for now nonetheless so thank you very much for the help :D

Comment: React router exposes a hook called `useHistory();` you can use said hook to get the current history from the router like this: `const history = useHistory();`. It also exposes other hooks like `useLocation()` `useParams()` and `useRouteMatch()`
If you want a simple tutorial, you can find it [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-react-router-include-router-hooks/), you can also go [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for the official lib docs.

Comment: If you want or need to learn more about how hooks work, which ones are available or how to create your own, you can go [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) or [here](https://medium.com/@guptagaruda/react-hooks-understanding-component-re-renders-9708ddee9928)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much again good sir